# MyBB Materialize Integration

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, mybb

Im interested to integrate Materializecss with a theme I would like to create for MyBB.

(Disclaimer: Not done this before, and new to php, css and html)

I was making reasonable progress and am able to place some Materialize elements where I want them, with the style I want.

However, I have hit a brick-wall, try as I might, I cannot figure this out.

For context, I am editing , and am concentrating on the buttons Edit, Delete, Reply etc..., the main block of code is

> Postbit Templates > postbit

```
<div class="post_controls_default">

<div class="postbit_buttons author_buttons float_left">
    {$post['button_www']}{$post['button_pm']}{$post['button_rep']}
</div>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-teal ban-flat">Material Button</a>
    <a class="btn-flat"><i class="material-icons left">edit</i>Edit Post</a>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="test5" />
  <label for="test5">Material Checkbox</label>
</p>
<div class="postbit_buttons post_management_buttons float_right">
    {$post['button_edit']}{$post['button_quickdelete']}{$post['button_quickrestore']}{$post['button_quote']}{$post['button_multiquote']}{$post['button_report']}{$post['button_warn']}{$post['button_purgespammer']}{$post['button_reply_pm']}{$post['button_replyall_pm']}{$post['button_forward_pm']}{$post['button_delete_pm']}

</div>
```

And the styling appears to be handled by

> global.css

```
.postbit_buttons > a:active {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #2c82c9;
    padding: 7px 16px 7px 14px;
    margin: 5px 2px 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #bed3e4;
}
```

Now the line of code that causing me to get confused

```
{$post['button_edit']}
```

Whats confusing me is, with my limited experience, I believe in order to create a button there needs to be a statement something like

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

However there is no such declaration here. If I remove the {$post['button_edit']} code, then the button is removed. If I put in another {$post['button_edit']} then I get another edit button, leading me to believe the  declaration is being built somewhere and I think $post has something to do with it.

After searching for everything I can think of, I have come up pretty dry. Found cross reference's to language translations and such like. So $push appears to be creating the button, and also supplying the text in the right language.

I found one block of code that looked hopeful in 'jquery.plugins' and 'jquery.plugins_e', at line 1030.

```
            // iterate over each button and create them
        for(i=0, l=buttons.length; i<l; i++){
            v = buttons[i],
            defbtn = stateobj.focus === i || (isNaN(stateobj.focus) && stateobj.defaultButton === i) ? (opts.prefix + 'defaultbutton ' + opts.classes.defaultButton) : '';

            state += '<button class="'+ opts.classes.button +' '+ opts.prefix + 'button '+ defbtn;

            if(typeof v.classes !== "undefined"){
                state += ' '+ ($.isArray(v.classes)? v.classes.join(' ') : v.classes) + ' ';
            }

            state += '" name="' + opts.prefix + '_' + statename + '_button' + v.title.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'') + '" value="' + v.value + '">' + v.title + '</button>';
        }
```

This appears to be building a  html declaration, but I can't find any relation to my actual problem (maybe through inexperience?) I tried changing some lines in ,js code to see what effect it had, but no effect was had on what I wanted.

I want to use material buttons throughout, and not the standard buttons and don't know the best way to approach this.

Is there a way of over-riding the default buttons in someway. So standard buttons get directed to Materialisze

I could just remove the {$post['button_edit']} and put my materialise code there, but I'm not sure how I would get the text / translation this way.

I don't have any problem going through and editing lots of templates and inserting all the materialize buttons where they need to be, if that is the way it needs to be done, but it just doesn't seem very efficient.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All button declarations do exist throughout the templates, it's just a case of finding them.

{$post['button_edit']} will direct you to postbit_edit.

In there exists the button declaration, this will need to be deleted and replace with the code for the materialize button, such as

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Material Button</a><a class="btn-flat"><i class="material-icons left">edit</i>Edit Post</a>
```

This will need to be done for every instance where you want to replace a button, to use the materialize one you want.

There is no easy way to make all existing buttons use the materialize button without modifying the individual instances where you want to reference materialize.